# Relation between factor graph and conditional probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, machine-learning

First, I'm from computer science. I don't know how to say this problem in a mathematical way. So please bear with me.

**The question**

Let say I have a factor graph illustrated in the figure.

[image: Factor graph]

The variables are $w,t,a$. The domain for $w,t,a$ is $\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\}$ and $\{0,1,2\}$ respectively. For the factors $h,g$, I know how to assign functions to them. For $h$, it can take a probability density function: $Pr(0) = 0.7, Pr(1)=0.3$. For $g$, it can be $Pr(0) = 0.2,Pr(1) = 0.3, Pr(2) = 0.5$. (Correct me if these assignments are wrong)

Then, I don't know how to assign a function to the factor $f$. Is it the conditional probability distribution function $p(t|w,a)$ ? 
If this is the case, do I need to define these three functions $p(t=0|w,a),p(t=1|w,a),p(t=2|w,a)$ given all possible values of $w$ and $a$ ?

**The setting**

The real world setting is the following: A user $w$ needs to label a data item $t$ to its correct value. The values which a data item $t$ can take are $0,1,2$. The value of the user can be $0,1$ - 0 means unreliable and 1 means reliable. $a$ is the label that the user have assigned to the data item. Therefore, I think $a$ is an observed variable and it can only take one value. From the factor graph and these values, I want to find the reliability of the user and the probability of correctness for each value of the data item.

Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a Bayesian Network with the 3 variables $w,a,t$ first, you can specify a joint distribution over them by reading the factorization from the graph. You can then convert the BN into this factor graph by assigning every term in the joint distribution to one of the factors.